# How to change VIEW when data arrives in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am calling a service from my component that returns me json data, Here is my code

```
import {Component,Input,Output} from 'angular2/core';
import {PostService} from './post.service';
import {OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
selector: 'postC',
template: `
 <div>
{{isLoading}}
</div>
`,
providers: [PostService]
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() isLoading = true;
@Input() y :any;
@Input() eventsArray;

constructor(private _postService: PostService){}
ngOnInit(){
    this._postService.getPost("California");
    this.y = this._postService.notifyParent
    .subscribe(item => {
        this.eventsArray = item.events.event[0];
        this.isLoading = false;
        console.log(this.isLoading);
    }) 
  }
}
```

here notifyParent = new EventEmitter() in my services component. Which emits event when it receives data.

The problems are:

1) isLoading is always showing true. Even after the observables updates its value to false.

2) I am not able to display the JSON data returned. Because the view already renders before I receive data.

There is a reason I am using event emitter and not http request. I am building this application for my school project and it has to run on localhost, which isn't able to make http reqests due to CORS issue.

Comment: Isn't the `getPost()` the one that returns the data? If it is shouldn't the `subscribe` be there?

Comment: It is just a call to function getPost()
which in turn has a callback function that emits the data through notifyParent event emitter.

Comment: and does that return the data ? so when you `console.log(this.eventsArray)` you have data there?

Comment: Yea it is returning data perfectly.

Comment: Ok! Why are the variables `@Input()` ? You are not using them as inputs. Just remove that and let me know if it worked.

Comment: No it didn't. i marked those as Inputs because I want the view to change whenever there is a change in value.

Comment: The view will automatically change if the value of anything that is used in the view changes. You use inputs when you want to pass data from the parent component to the child component. So if in the parent component view, where you use this component you would do `<postC [isLoading]="false">` and the value would be false. When you console.log(this.isLoading) does it show true or false? If it show false there's a problem in the change detection.

Comment: I initially set isLoading  = true. whenever the observable triggers and data is received it is set to false, which is what my console displays.

Comment: So the code of your service is probably breaking angular zones and angular doesn't run change detection on the subscribe... import `ChangeDetectorRef`, put it on your constructor `(cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef)` and on the subscribe run `cdRef.detectChanges()`. This will trigger the angular 2 change detection manually. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @JoelAlmeida Thanks a lot man! It worked!

Comment: Glad to help! Added as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your service for some reason is breaking the angular zone, so when you subscribe the change detection doesn't run.

We can force the change detection manually. Import `ChangeDetectorRef` and run `detectChanges()` in your subscribe.

```
import {Component,Input,Output,ChangeDetectorRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {PostService} from './post.service';
import {OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
selector: 'postC',
template: `
 <div>
{{isLoading}}
</div>
`,
providers: [PostService]
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
public isLoading = true;
public y :any;
public eventsArray;

constructor(private _postService: PostService, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef){}
ngOnInit(){
    this._postService.getPost("California");
    this.y = this._postService.notifyParent
    .subscribe(item => {
        this.eventsArray = item.events.event[0];
        this.isLoading = false;
        console.log(this.isLoading);
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not getting response, try to check console error, in error:

```
errorMessage: any;

ngOnInit(){
  this._postService.getPost("California");
  this.y = this._postService.notifyParent
  .subscribe(item => {
    this.eventsArray = item.events.event[0];
    this.isLoading = false;
    console.log(this.isLoading);
  },
  error=> {
    this.errorMessage = <any> error
    console.log("error: ", this.errorMessage);
  }) 
}
```

Now if you are getting error, then check your service.

Comment: I am able to display the data on the console. Also the isLoading prints false on console. Problem is, it's value is not changing in the view which still displays it as true.

PS: Tried your code. No errors logged

Comment: I am not sure, but try to make this abject and try: dataStatus = {isLoading: true} and bind this in @Input.